# How to store value of a textbox without losing focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, local-storage

I am trying to store value in a textbox. It works fine if I enter a value in the text box and then click outside the textbox and refresh it. I want to know if it is possible to just enter a value in the textbox and directly refresh the page without clicking outside the textbox?

Here is the script:

```
 <script>
 jQuery(function ($) {
   if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {
    //set the value to the text fields
    $("input[type=text]").val(function () {
        return localStorage.getItem(this.id);
    });

    $("input[type=text]").on("change", function () {
        localStorage.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
    });
     }
 });
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hb8eW/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hb8eW/15/

Use `keyup` event instead of `change` event.

```
$("input[type=text]").on("keyup", function () {
    localStorage.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: If you don't mind what is the difference between keyup and keypress?

Comment: Keypress fires before the value is sent, keyup fires after.

Comment: `keyup` - fires after the character is inserted.(after user releases the key) where as `keypress` - Fires when an actual character is being inserted in. More info here - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this would be to listen for a keyup event within the form field rather than the change event.

```
$("input[type=text]").on("keyup", function () {
    localStorage.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle that demonstrates how this would work.
http://jsfiddle.net/hb8eW/16/

... and here's a quick fiddle that demonstrates the difference between jQuery's keypress, keyup, and change events. Note when content is updated after different events (and that keypress is always one character behind).
http://jsfiddle.net/krainey/UhR85/

You can read about keyup here:
http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 0):

The change event is only triggered when the textbox loses focus. You can use the keyup event instead to refresh immediately.